# Carga lento Gradle en Android Studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Recién acabo de instalar el *Android Studio*, y se demora en cargar *Gradle*. Tengo **8 GB de memoria RAM** y un procesador ***Intel core 7***.

> Resolve dependencies: `app:debugAndroidTestApkC`.

Comment: Ps si el programa demora bastante y mas aun en la maquina virtual usa esto: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/how-to-make-android-studio-fast.html

Comment: ¿Qué es lento? ¿Cuándo sufres esa ralentización? ¿Qué sistema operativo usas y de qué arquitectura (32 o 64 bits)? ¿Tienes antivirus?

Comment: Deshabilita la opción Offline Work  y comenta resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Deshabilita la opción  **Offline Work**

`File` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Gradle` > **`Offline Work`**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya lo tenia desactivado.

Comment: ¿Para que sirve esa opcion?

Comment: @Diego si ya tienes descargadas las dependencias no las vuelve a descargar y puedes trabajar sin conexión a internet.

Answer (score 0):

En el `gradle.properties` agrega esto

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

y cambiar en los gradle del proyecto todos los `jcenter()` por `mavenCentral()`

Espero que te sea de ayuda.